# Access the control of one page from another page

Tags: javascript, html

In my project, I need to disable some controls in one page from an another page. For example Mainpage.html has a button named "View profile", which needs to be disabled from Profile.html. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot write server side code to process actions for plain-vanilla HTML pages. You will need to use client side scripts (read 'Javascript') to implement your functionality.

Answer (score 1):

On the profile page set a cookie that is read on Mainpage.html, depending on whether its set or not the control is disabled.

Comment: Well its tagged for javascript so I assume that was implied.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I didnt think the OP was using just vanilla html.